# Not able to register my ArcGIS Notebook Server in Portal

Tags: arcgis-server

How to overcome **"Failed to federate ArcGIS Server site [...] with Portal for ArcGIS. Failed to update security configuration for ArcGIS Server [...]"** when registering server with ArcGIS Portal.

I was not able to register my ArcGIS Notebook Server in my Portal for ArcGIS. I tried to add my server...

[image]

... but I got following error message after clicking `Add`:

> Failed to federate ArcGIS Server site 'https://MY_NOTEBOOK_DOMAIN:11443/arcgis' with Portal for ArcGIS. Failed to update security configuration for ArcGIS Server 'https://MY_NOTEBOOK_DOMAIN:11443/arcgis'.

> The server at 'https://MY_NOTEBOOK_DOMAIN:11443/arcgis/admin/security/config/update' returned an error. Failed to update the security configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the solution was quite simple...

My ArcGIS Notebook Server machine (`MY_NOTEBOOK_DOMAIN`) was not allowed to access my Portal for ArcGIS machine (`MY_PORTAL_DOMAIN`) using port `7443`.

My `MY_PORTAL_DOMAIN`'s firewall disallowed port `7443`.

**Solution:** Allow incoming traffic using port `7443` on `MY_PORTAL_DOMAIN` during setup.

---

I found the cause thanks to this error in my logs on your ArcGIS Notebook Server:

> Failed to update the security configuration. Cannot update security configuration to federate with the portal as the server is not registered with the portal. Could not connect to the ArcGIS component at URL 'https://MY_PORTAL_DOMAIN:**7443**/arcgis/sharing/rest/portals/self'. The ArcGIS component on that machine may not be running, or the machine may not be reachable at this time.Error: Read timed out